# Post data using AJAX then retrieving the value of JSON array

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying to create a validation to check if my data already exist or not using Ajax. It's works, but now I want to add JSON inside my Ajax php file and retrieve the array inside of the JSON, unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.

Take a look at my JQuery below :

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var tempcode = $('#someobject').val();

    $.ajax({

        method:"POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url:'example.php',
        data:{
            Code: tempcode
            },
        success:function(data){
            var my = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(my.Title);
        }

    });
});
```

And below is example.php :

```
 $AJAXCode = $_POST['Code'];
 $myObj = array();



 $strSQL = mysql_query("select * from sometable where Code ='$AJAXCode'");
 $check = mysql_num_rows($strSQL);

 if ($AJAXCode == NULL) {
    $myObj->Title= "Choose Something";
    $myObj->Total = $check;

    $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
    echo $myJSON;
 } else {
    if ($check != 0) {

        $myObj->Title= "Already Exist !";
        $myObj->Total = $check;

        $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
        echo $myJSON;

    }   else {

        $myObj->Title= "You are good !!!";;
        $myObj->Total = $check;

        $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
        echo $myJSON;           
    }
 }
```

As you can see at my JQuery scripts, I am trying to call "Title" inside my JSON array, but it doesn't work. Am I missing something ?

This is the result in Console.log, no error show up just this:

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get a javascript error? Do you get an alert with something in it?

Comment: no, not even alert show up

Comment: Take a look in the developer tools of your browser and make sure the request returns the correct value.

Comment: Comment out alert and parse lines and add `console.log(data)` and see what you get. If there is nothing, then add a method `error:function..` just like the `success` one and see what that outputs you.

Comment: @DainisAbols console log said : Empty string passed to getElementById(). , what should i do ?

Comment: The `getElementById` console error - which line is that referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you initialize your object the wrong way. Use instead of `$myObj = array();` one of the following:

```
$myObj = (object) array();

or

$myObj = new StdClass();
```

For more information and more ways to create your object, look up [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#118679) link.

Next, change the [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) attribute to:

```
dataType: "json"
```

in order to tell your script that your PHP response is encoded as JSON. You can use now your response the regular way, with `JSON.parse()`, try:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```

Comment: still same, console.log said :
Empty string passed to getElementById()

Comment: Then you don't get a response. Check the php side

Comment: replace your `echo $myJSON` with `echo json_encode("foo");` and try it again.

Comment: same conclusion, Empty string passed bla bla, and what is "foo" anyway ?

Comment: You tried `console.log(data)`? Because you wrote that you get an `getElementById()`-error, which is another function than `console.log()`...

Comment: `foo` (and also `bar`) are the mostly used placeholders in programming :) check out this link for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: yes, i tried console.log, but get and error Empty string passed to getElementById() . if i tried to alert $('#someobject').val() , it returning the value of object correctly. so what did i do wrong ?

Comment: You get a `getELementById()`-error if you use `console.log()`? Sounds veery strange to me. Please comment all other code in your success-function to execute just this `console.log()`-statement.

Comment: i just add picture of my console above, you can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks. Click on the link the right side of the error line and you'll get redirected to your JS-File at the right position: Is the error thrown at the position of the `console.log()`?

Comment: unfortunately i dont have a required repuation for chat, sorry.

Comment: No worries, just stay here in the comment section. Have you checked my mentioned line?

Comment: It return some kind of code i don't understand, here what it said : (function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),function(e,n){t[n]=!0}),t}function H(e,n,r){if(r===t&&e.nodeType===1){var i="data-"+n.replace(P,"-$1").toLowerCase();r=e.getAttribute(i);if(typeof r=="string"){try{r=r==="true"?!0:r==="false"?!1:r==="null", bla bla ... its too long. its inside of  jquery.min.js . is this help ?

Comment: Am I doing the right thing for creating JSON array in "example.php" ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didn't read your PHP enough carefully. You had a problem with creating your object - check out my updated answer.

Comment: now i got another problem, the Code that i post always returning NULL value. And the console.log(JSON.parse(data)); only work if i make the datatype: text, if I make datatype: json. it doesn't work and will return error -> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Nevermind, I just copied the last code worked then changed the value one by one, then its work again.... maybe i got typo in the middle way. thanks man

Comment: By the way, I use dataType:text, if I use dataType:json, it doesn't work at all, oh well at least i got the result i want

Comment: Ok, cool that your code works now as expected, altough the `json` datatype is basically correct here but we'll ignore that as long as it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace Below Code :

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var tempcode = $('#someobject').val();

$.ajax({

    method:"POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url:'example.php',
    data:{
        Code: tempkode
        },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data.Title); // Example
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Empty string passed to getElementById() , that's what it said in console

Comment: write console.log(data);

Answer (score 0):

Change variable tempkode to tempcode in data

Comment: just a typo, sorry. above is my actual code. and it still not working